# ngspice .measure syntax in AC + par()

Tags: mosfet, impedance, ngspice

Why do the [two netlists](https://www.diffchecker.com/N6pEXqyD) give totally [different output impedance values](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Nf5x8rsxKx/) ?

[image: netlist 1 run log]

[image: netlist 2 run log]

**Netlist 1:**

```
*CMOS inverter https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383552/measurement-of-output-impedance-of-a-cmos-inverter
.PARAM V_SUPPLY = 3.3
.PARAM AC_POINTS = 10
.PARAM AC_START = 1000
.PARAM AC_STOP = 1E6
VDD VDD 0 'V_SUPPLY'
VSS VSS 0 0
MP OUT IN VDD VDD P1 W='9.987275E-06' L=3.500000E-07
MN OUT IN VSS VSS N1 W='9.987275E-06/2' L=3.500000E-07 
CIN IN VSS 1E9
Rf OUT IN 1E9
IOUT VSS OUT AC 1
.AC dec 'AC_POINTS' 'AC_START' 'AC_STOP'
.OPTION POST PROBE ACCURATE
.include modelcard.nmos
.include modelcard.pmos
.MEASURE AC Zac_power0 rms par('abs(i(vdd))*v(vdd)')
.measure AC ZROUT1 rms par('v(OUT)/abs(i(VSS))')
.end
```

**Netlist 2:**

```
*CMOS inverter https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383552/measurement-of-output-impedance-of-a-cmos-inverter
.PARAM V_SUPPLY = 3.3
.PARAM AC_POINTS = 10
.PARAM AC_START = 1000
.PARAM AC_STOP = 1E6
VDD VDD 0 'V_SUPPLY'
VSS VSS 0 0
MP OUT IN VDD VDD P1 W='9.987275E-06' L=3.500000E-07
MN OUT IN VSS VSS N1 W='9.987275E-06/2' L=3.500000E-07
CIN IN VSS 1E9
Rf OUT IN 1E9
IOUT VSS OUT AC 1
.OPTION POST PROBE ACCURATE
.include modelcard.nmos
.include modelcard.pmos
.control
*AC dec 'AC_POINTS' 'AC_START' 'AC_STOP'
AC dec 10 1000 1E6

let ROUT=OUT/abs(i(VSS))
plot ROUT
print ROUT > ROUT.log
.endc

.END
```

For exact problem duplication, just copy the two netlists into two different files and run ngspice. Cross-check the terminal output with mine as shown above.

The modelcard.pmos and model.nmos can be found at https://github.com/promach/frequency_trap/blob/development/optimization/inv

Comment: Netlist 2 doesn't have a proper analysis statement.

Comment: @HKOB Someone told me "meaning of RMS (root - mean - square), which is defined for real t,y tuples (values sampled at time points), when we apply it to a list of complex values where 'time' is another list of complex values". However, In this case, how should I modify .measure AC ZROUT1 rms par('v(OUT)/abs(i(VSS))') in order to avoid involving 'time' values in the ZROUT1 result computation ?

Comment: @HKOB Netlist 2 is from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383552/measurement-of-output-impedance-of-a-cmos-inverter which gives correct spice simulation output relative to theoretical calculation. Pleasee see carefully the link. Why netlist 2 does not have proper analysis statement ?

Comment: The difference between the two is the dot AC and .AC. I don't really have ngspice experience - maybe it accepts both. In the logs only one of the runs shows an ac analysis simulation.

Comment: With the only AC source being the output load current you only need to plot V(out) to get Zout (if Ac magnitude = 1). Take the magnitude of Zout near DC to find Rout

Comment: Also I suggest you could replace your mosfets with a resistor while you debug :)

Comment: @HKOB "AC" is treated as a behavioral model element, not as an ".AC" analysis.